# Get permanent Token for Twitter App in tmhOAuth (Twitter PHP SDK)

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using tmhOAuth as PHP API for connecting my twitter app. Every time user tries to tweet through my app, The user need to authorize app every time even if he has authorized earlier. Is there a way I could find out whether the user is logged in and already authorized the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there has not been any response for the problem, and I have somehow succeeded in solving the problem. The solution is pretty straight and simple. You just need to hit `/authenticate` rather than `/authorize` as the hitting URL. This will handle the log in and permission flow by it self.

Comment: That works.. great!! Can u plz tell how can I save these tokens in my back end to correlate it with particular user.